# Count the number of lines in a pdf file

Tags: bash, pdf, latex

How is it possible to count the number of lines in a pdf file? Preferably from the linux command line (`bash`)?

The `pdf`s I want to analyse are generated using LaTeX, so any solution working on the tex sources would be fine as well (as long as the results are the same as when counting in the pdf manually and the resulting pdf is not modified).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try using [pdftotext](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext)

```
pdftotext -layout file.pdf - | wc -l
```

The `-layout` option may not be necessary. I'd say some experimentation is in order.

You could also use `wc` on the tex sources directly, but this will probably not give you the same result as measuring the PDFs, since the tex files will contain lines that will not be visible in the final PDF.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect. The problem with using `wc` on the tex sources directly is not that there are additional commands, but that the generated pdf has additional line breaks which I am interested in.